# Prevent bluetooth keyboard from losing connection to android tablet

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth, external-keyboard

I have an Android 6 tablet (Sasmung Galaxy Tab S 10.5 if it matters) and use a bluetooth keyboard with it. After a few minutes of being idle, the keyboard loses the connection. To reactivate it, I have to start pressing buttons on the keyboard, and wait a couple of seconds to start reading the keystrokes again. I want to prevent this 'standby' feature. Is there a setting?

EDIT: FYI: the most annoying side effect of this disconnection/reconnection of the keyboard is that video playback behaves strangely. Namely, it suddenly starts, or some other times it stops while I'm watching something or jumps to a different time point or a different video from the playlist. This happens with VLC and another app (Safari Queue) that has an integrated video player. I haven't tried other audio/video players but I'm guessing this a general problem and not something to do with the two apps I mentioned.

Comment: See if this app helps https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.myklos.btautoconnect

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks for the suggestion, I tried btautoconnect for the past few days but unfortunately the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The connection loss over bluetooth is a feature of the keyboard itself. 
Bluetooth 5 is little better than previous versions, but still you can only minimise the connection loss little because of the wireless nature of the connection and there is always a gap there which can lead to a connection loss. 
BT5 should however be much more stable but end devices are still short in supply.

Differential solution: USB-C keyboard later if supported.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will see if I get different results with a better BT keyboard.